# Instantiating an object inside another object? (c#)

Tags: c#, class, oop, edx

Firstly I'd like to say that I truly sorry if this is an idiotic question but I just started learning about Classes and I've thought that I managed to understand it but this confused the heck outta me so seems like I didn't

I'm doing this C# OOP edx course where I had to make 5 classes (student, teacher, UProgram, degree, course) in different class files and there's this task:

[image: a pic that was included]

> 1. Instantiate a UProgram object called Information Technology.
> 2. Instantiate a Degree object, such as Bachelor, insude the UProgram object.
> 3. Instantiate a Course object called softeng inside the Degree object.

1. Was done, (hopefully) no issues with that one
2. and 3. - eh.

How I was thinking (bear in mind, im a beginner so):
First I've thought of nested classes but I wasn't really sure about how they work and didn't think I could put the classes in different files as they should be nested (?)
And then I tried something with the constructor but I couldn't see how I could make it work

So now my final try was to create methods inside the classes (except for the Teacher and Student one as they won't have anything ""belonging to them"" like a Course has students and teachers belonging to it

So I have the method in the form of (- let's say we're in the Degree class, having a method for creating several Courses for this degree -):

```
public void Newcourse(string Cname, Course sth)
{
    sth = new Course();
    sth = Cname;
}
```

And before I can use it, I have to write the

```
Course softeng = new Course();
```

line aka make an instance of the Course class before I can do the 3. point of the task

The whole code:

**UProgram.cs**

```
public class UProgram
{
    public void Newdegree(string Dname, Degree sth)
    {
        sth = new Degree();
        sth.Dname = Dname;
    }
}
```

**Degree.cs**

```
public class Degree : UProgram
{
    public string Dname { get; set; }
    public void Newcourse(string Cname, Course sth)
    {
        sth = new Course();
        sth.Cname = Cname;
    }
}
```

**Course.cs**

```
public class Course : Degree
{
    public void NewTeacher(string FirstName, string LastName, Teacher sth)
    {
        sth = new Teacher();
        sth.FirstName = FirstName;
        sth.LastName = LastName;
    }
    public void NewStudent(string FirstName, string LastName, Student sth)
    {
        sth = new Student();
        sth.FirstName = FirstName;
        sth.LastName = LastName;
    }
    public string Cname { get; set; }
}
```

**Teacher.cs**

```
public class Teacher : Course
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student : Course
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Information_Technology = new UProgram();
            Degree bachelors = new Degree();
            Information_Technology.Newdegree("Bachelors", bachelors);
            Course softeng = new Course();
            bachelors.Newcourse("Software Engineering", softeng);
            Teacher t1 = new Teacher();
            softeng.NewTeacher("Colin", "Firth", t1);
            Student s1 = new Student();
            softeng.NewStudent("Mary", "Sue", s1);
            Student s2 = new Student();
            softeng.NewStudent("Joseph", "Jojo", s2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I know-I know, it's very convoluted and I'm not even sure whether this is good or not but that was all I could come up with and I'd be very grateful if any of you could help me out (in a tone that won't make me cry)

Thank you and again, sorry for this mess of a code, eh, i tried

Comment: Please take your time to review and understand this statement: `Teacher : Course`, which means something like: a Teacher is a Course. Do you think that this make sense?

Comment: Take care not to confuse class hierarchy with data hierarchy. This is a class hierarchy - inheritance that is - which is not the answer. Instead of instantiating everything in main, you should for example instantiate Course inside Degree. Only UIProgram needs instantiating in main.

Comment: Upvoted for the effort shown.

Answer (score 3):

The wording does seem a bit strange, but I believe they are simply saying that this class should contain a property of the type it is meant to "contain", and instantiate it in the constructor. For example:

```
public class Degree
{
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public Degree()
    {
        Course = new Course();
    }
}

public class Course
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        Student = new Student();
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {

    }
}
```

Upon creating a an instance of Degree, it will create an instance of a Course inside it, which will create an instance of a Student inside it. Thus Degree contains a Course which contains a Student.

The example above is using the constructors to instantiate these but as they are public properties they could also just be created from outside it (in which case the constructors above are unnecessary):

```
var degree = new Degree();
degree.Course = new Course();
degree.Course.Student = new Student();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a few comments:

I have big doubts that you need any inheritance here. For example: *Student : Course* - I doubt that "Student is a Course" :) . So, you probably need some composition here. I don't know (and can't remember) what diamonds in your picture exactly means, but can guess that filled diamond - is one item (or at least one, not sure) and empty means many items.
So, here how I would do this (you can split each class to separate file):

```
public class UProgram
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Degree Degree { get; set; }

    public UProgram(string name, Degree degree)
    {
        Name = name;
        Degree = degree;
    }
}

public class Degree
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public Degree(string name, Course course)
    {
        Name = name;
        Course = course;
    }
}

public class Course
{
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Course(string name, List<Teacher> teachers, List<Student> students)
    {
        Name = name;
        Teachers = teachers;
        Students = students;
    }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and Main function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var teachers = new List<Teacher>
        {
            new Teacher
            {
                FirstName = "Colin",
                LastName = "Firth"
            }
        };
        var students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Mary",
                LastName = "Sue"
            },
            new Student
            {
                FirstName = "Joseph",
                LastName = "Jojo"
            }
        };

        var softEngCourse = new Course("Software Engineering", teachers, students);
        var bachelorDegree = new Degree("Bachelor", softEngCourse);

        var technologyProgram = new UProgram("Technology", bachelorDegree);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I still not sure that this exactly what your course is expected from you, this is how I would write code like this (with some minor changes, but it doesn't matter here).
Why in that way? Because it is almost always better to build an object in a "working" state when it explicitly receives everything that it needs, rather than create a raw object that will start in "invalid" state. Secondly, it is usually better to not "bake in" parameters values inside, but give a class consumer (I mean "developer" here) to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the task. `Course` should not inherit from `Degree`, since `Course` is not a `Degree`. Instead, you will need to define `Course` data member in your `Degree` class. Neither `Student`, nor `Teacher` is a `Course`, therefore you should not inherit them from `Course`. They are members.

I assume that a `Degree` can be achieved by a single `Course`.

I assume that a `Course` has a single `Teacher`.

I assume that a `Course` can have multiple `Students`.

This means that you have a `Person` class, like this, since both `Student` and `Teacher` is a `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Now, inherit `Teacher` from `Person`:

```
public class Teacher : Person {
    public Teacher(String firstName, String lastName) : base(firstName, lastName) {
    }
}
```

and `Student`:

```
public class Student : Person {
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) : base(firstName, lastName) {
    }
}
```

Now, let's define `Course`:

```
public class Course {
    protected Teacher teacher;
    protected List<Student> students;
    protected String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return this.teacher;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return this.students;
    }

    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.teacher = new Teacher(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        this.students.Add(student);
    }

    public void addStudent(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.students.Add(new Student(firstName, lastName));
    }

    public Course(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.students = new List<Student>();
    }
}
```

Now, let's define `Degree`:

```
public class Degree {
    protected String name;
    protected Course course;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return this.course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String name) {
        this.course = new Course(name);
    }

    public Degree(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now, this is how you achieve what you wanted:

```
Degree degree = new Degree("mydegree");
degree.setCourse("myCourse");
Course course = degree.getCourse();
course.setTeacher("John", "Smith");
course.addStudent("James", "Doe");
```